# How to create my custom Command Line Interface (CLI) in a project

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line-interface

I really want to know how I can build my own Command Line Interface CLI for my project.

CLI was very efficient and competent for developers. I really like to use CLI for any project since it make development more faster. For example I will use CLI given by ionicframework in the document to create new project:

E.g: `ionic start myApp blank`

It was good if I able to create my own folder and certain files with my custom CLI.

For example, if I use my CLI:

```
module welcome // This my sample CLI
```

When I wrote that, the command will create certain files, for example:

```
1. welcome folder
   - welcome.css
   - welcome.js
   - welcome.html
```

Anyone knows how to do such that?

Comment: do you have an answer?

Comment: Not yet @OlafErlandsen ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a scaffolder for your application (i personally use this: https://github.com/paulmillr/scaffolt)

This allows you to create custom generators and then create folders and files based on what you setup in your generator.

I personally use this to generate pages, services and directives in my angular and ionic projects.

It's very easy to use.

Let's say you want to create a template like you asked above, all you have to do is:

`scaffolt -g generator/page welcome page`

and a new folder called page will be generated with a bunch of files in it.

Breaking down the command above:

`-g`: Tell scaffolt you are gonna use a generator
`generator/page`: This may change and it points to the folder where your generators are
`welcome`: This is the name of your module
`page`: This is the generator to use

Another nice thing about this scaffolt is that you can use handlebars for templating as well as create helpers.

Fir instance I have helpers to handle the name in different ways.

One to put all lowercase, one to capitalise and one to convert the name to camelCase.

I hope this gives you a starting point, and even if this is more than an year old, the principle of scaffolt can be used on basically any projects (i use it for wordpress theme development, ionic apps, plugins, basic website boilerplates and so on)